# Castle.MicroKernel resolve is not resolving dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm using *Assembly Castle.MicroKernel.dll, v2.0.50727* in a legacy project and is calling

```
object Resolve(Type service, object argumentsAsAnonymousType);
```

In the code, the call is

```
kernal.Resolve(Z, new { entityX, entityY, entityZ });
```

where the *entityX, entityY and entityZ* are dynamically generated objects from the database.

The call gives the following errors. The error is

> the type of entityX was not registered
>
> A is waiting for the following dependencies:
>
> Services: 
>   - type of entityX which was not registered. 
>   - C which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.
>
> C is waiting for the following dependencies:
>
> Keys (components with specific keys)
>   - type of entityY which was not registered. 
>   - type of entityZ was not registered. 
>   - F was not registered.

Should I inject/register entityX, entityY and entityZ into the kernel or any container for the resolving the dependent object?

Comment: What does the constructor of `Z` that you're expecting to use look like?  Castle matches arguments based on their name, so they need to match.  Also what is `A`, `C`, and `F`? Are they dependencies of `Z`?

Comment: Also you say _Castle.MicroKernel.dll, v2.0.50727_, but that's not an assembly I've seen, nor is it a [released version of Castle Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/402503f011b4bbe323a92f0f5b240ece3350509a/Changes.txt#L329-L347), which includes the Microkernel.  I think you're looking at the "Runtime Version", not the "Version" in the propery grid, but of what assembly I don't really know...